# Config (PhpStorm 2017.2.3 + Google App Engine SDK PHP 1.9.57) Dir valid..?

Tags: google-app-engine, phpstorm

I have a problem with the SDK.

What can be the problem with the path, in `D:\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin` are the files shown in the last print.

I hope you can help me.

Print: https://s26.postimg.org/d4spx9usp/print_de_pantalla_64.jpg
[image]

Zoom Text: https://s26.postimg.org/aeje02y3t/print_de_pantalla_66.jpg
[image]

Tree Dir SDK Install: https://s26.postimg.org/sstx42aeh/print_de_pantalla_65.jpg
[image]

Version Google App Engine SDK PHP: https://s26.postimg.org/3pcuk2crt/print_de_pantalla_67.jpg
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I already found the solution to the problem, I leave it so that others can find it too, simple.

With just installing the Google App SDK PHP is not enough.

Then on the console you have to execute the following command.

```
gcloud components install app-engine-php
```

[image]

Creating the following folder is the one that searches for PHPStorm to take as valid the path.

Tree Dirs: https://s26.postimg.org/vhxwlkund/print_de_pantalla_70.jpg
[image]

Is ok set path SDK: https://s26.postimg.org/z824s7vvt/print_de_pantalla_71.jpg
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Linux run:
`which gcloud`

It will outputs something like this:
`/home/username/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud`

PS: you may have different paths

Then Simply go to `google-cloud-sdk` folder and then `platform` folder in it.
You will get google-appengine folder,

if not then probably sdk was not properly installed, just run this command again to install app-engine sdk

For Python:  `gcloud components install app-engine-python`

For Others: [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads)

Answer (score -1):

If you use gcloud from ubuntu repositories, then the path for google-cloud-sdk is this one:

cd /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/

Comment: According to the screenshots, the OP obviously uses Windows