# How can i setup remote project with PhpStorm with Google Compute Engine running LEMP?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, phpstorm, google-compute-engine

I was working on a web cloud app and setup Google compute Engine with micro instance (Ubuntu 14.4) with nginx, Laravel, MySQL and PHP.

Now I want to setup my PhpStorm IDE with this setup to make development fast.

Kindly help me with this thing.

Comment: Please provide list of **exact** issues that you are having. Otherwise it looks like: "I do not want/have time to read the manual and want somebody else to *guess* what I'm may be doing wrong/how to do it".

Comment: But in general: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Getting+Started+with+PhpStorm+as+Google+App+Engine+PHP+IDE this and other official manuals 2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/46231376/783119

Comment: I think are you mention about the ftp of PhpStorm ? yes, you can set up that on GC, but clearly state your question. so we can help you.

Comment: Yes,  i was talking about ftp setup. Thank hou Roman Gherta,  It was really helpful. I setup my IDE using  instructions described by you.

Comment: No problem. Glad you're using GCP.

Comment: Hi Jitander, can I ask you to accept my answer? there is a green checkbox to the left of my answer

Comment: Thank You, Yes I Accepted. Sorry for delay brother. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make development faster with PHPStorm follow the steps below:

1. Make sure you generate a SSH key-pair(public+private) with PuttyGen.
2. Paste the contents of your *public* key in GCE in the SSH Key section.
   [image]

You can find that section when you go to Edit menu of your GCE instance.

3. Go to PHPStorm and enter data for your remote host in Tools/Deployment/Configuration
4. Choose SFTP and browse and enter the path to your *private* key in "Private Key File" field.

[image]

Now test your connection and enjoy rapid deployment with PHPStorm and GCP