# Edit file permissions using SFTP to Google Cloud Engine Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, macos, google-cloud-platform, filezilla

My goal is to update 1 file on my Wordpress website on Google Cloud Engine using Filezilla to transfer it.

I am successfully logged into my files using SFTP. I'm on a Mac. I have my vm instance name from Google Cloud Engine but cannot find how to create a password.

I think if I can figure out how to create a ding dang password my next step is to type this in terminal:
sudo chwown "vm-name" /var/www/html

Any direction is much appreciated. My website has been down since yesterday b/c I messed with https plugin. I'm a designer and got in way over my head. Learned more than bargained for so far.

Answer (score 0):

To run any linux command inside your instance you need to:

1. Generate a private/public key pair using Puttygen.
2. You need to add the content of your public key to GCP as in below answer.

[How can i setup remote project with PhpStorm with Google Compute Engine running LEMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389911/how-can-i-setup-remote-project-with-phpstorm-with-google-compute-engine-running/46517240#46517240)

3. You need to open Putty.
4. In the Session menu enter yourusername@instance_external_ip as a hostname using connection type SSH
5. In the menu Connection/SSH/Auth browse and select your private key(the one generated at step 1).
6. Click Open. A new terminal window will open. You will be abel to navigate inside your linux instance and do whatever sudo commands you wish.

Good luck